# Get $stateParams without ui-nav

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can you somehow receive $stateParams without having a `<ui-view>`-tag in your html?

Basically, I want this code to work:

```
.config([
  '$locationProvider',
  '$stateProvider',
function($locationProvider, $stateProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
  .state('schedules_show', {
    name: 'edit_schedule',
    url: '/schedules/:id/edit'
  });

}])
```

So I can fetch the :id from any other controller that is being called via $stateParams.

**Some more clarification:** I don't want to use $stateParams to generate links or to move around my application, cause my app is an hybrid of RoR and Angular.js. I change views in server side with common links. I just want to use angular-ui-router to get some values from the URL to use in the Angular.js part of my app (in this case the :id). So because I don't want to navigate via Angular and don't want to use it's state dependent controllers or views, which again is the reason why I don't want to have `<ui-view>`-tags in my HTML.

**Problem solved:** I think my approach via `angular-ui-router` was wrong. I have a solution now, where I just pass the param from the HTML via ng-init to the controller, but it doesn't answer my question, so I think this should be closed.

Comment: what do you mean by without having a tag?

Comment: Sorry, i had written <ui-view> there and SO made interpreted it as HTML

Comment: So why do you use Angular then?

Comment: I need it just partly on single pages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you rigth you need state params. And the qnswer is: yes you can. First way is to use url params: `/url/suburl/:param1/:param2/:paramN`. Second way (if you do not want to see your params in url) use `params` option in your state. Then just call your state with this params inside. Example:

`.state('schedules_show', {
    name: 'state1',
    url: '/state',
    params: {
        param1: null,
        param2: null
    }
});`

Here, in state configuration `null` is for not to assign initial value; and call this state with

`ui-sref="state1({ param1: 'test', param2: 10 })"`

Then in injected `$stateParams` object you can get these params' values

Another possible solution is to use `resolve` in your state to provide specific params to your controller assigned with this state

More info about [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Does it makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but unfortunately is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Why? You need a solution without `ui-view`. Am I wrong? If not, this is possible solution. You do not need to include `ui-view` in this case.

Comment: I added a clarification to my post. You also can see above that I already have params embed in my state url in the code.